# Taking values from other rows matching by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one problem with SQL query. I have the following table in SQL server 2014.

```
declare @t table (STORE_ID int, INDEX_ID int, START_DATE datetime,
              END_DATE datetime, 
              GROSS_SALES_PRICE decimal(10,2),
              NET_SALES_PRICE INT 
             );

insert into @t 
values (3,22,'2014-08-01 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-30 23:59:59.000', 29.99,25),
       (3,22,'2014-10-01 00:00:00.000', '2014-12-31 23:59:59.000', NULL,NULL),
       (3,22,'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-09-30 23:59:59.000', 39.99,28),
       (4,22,'2016-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-07-31 23:59:59.000', 29.99,25),
       (4,22,'2016-08-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-12-31 23:59:59.000', NULL,NULL),
       (4,22,'2017-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2018-09-30 23:59:59.000', 39.99,28),
       (1,22,'2014-08-30 00:00:00.000', '2014-10-31 23:59:59.000', 39.99,28),
       (1,22,'2014-11-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-09-30 23:59:59.000', 20.99,15)
```

As you can see there are some NULLS in `GROSS_SALES_PRICE`and `NET_SALES_PRICE` in some rows. The case is to take this prices from the rows where `STORE_ID` equals 1. For example if you have NULL values in second row you can take prices from this peroid from Store number 1. But in this peroid you have 2 diferent prices. So you have to split that NULL line into two lines and take 2 diferent prices. If there is no maching part of the peroid the part of the row should be left as NULL. All dates are separable. The result should look like this.

```
declare @t2 table (STORE_ID int, INDEX_ID int, START_DATE datetime,
              END_DATE datetime, 
              GROSS_SALES_PRICE decimal(10,2),
              NET_SALES_PRICE INT 
             );

insert into @t2 
values (3,22,'2014-08-01 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-30 23:59:59.000', 29.99,25),
       (3,22,'2014-10-01 00:00:00.000', '2014-10-31 23:59:59.000', 39.99,28),
       (3,22,'2014-11-01 00:00:00.000', '2014-12-31 23:59:59.000', 20.99,15),
       (3,22,'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-09-30 23:59:59.000', 39.99,28),
       (4,22,'2016-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-07-31 23:59:59.000', 29.99,25),
       (4,22,'2016-08-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-09-30 23:59:59.000', 20.99,15),
       (4,22,'2016-10-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-12-31 23:59:59.000', NULL,NULL),
       (4,22,'2017-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2018-09-30 23:59:59.000', 39.99,28),
       (1,22,'2014-08-30 00:00:00.000', '2014-10-31 23:59:59.000', 39.99,28),
       (1,22,'2014-11-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-09-30 23:59:59.000', 20.99,15)
```

Comment: As discussed on your previous question, that method of date ranges is questionable. See also:  [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A calendar/dates table can simplify this, but we can also use a query to generate a temporary dates table using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Joining to the prices for each  `index_id` from `store_id 1` cross joined with a dates table lets us join and aggregate to get the prices for the missing values. Then using `union all` to return the rows with a price, and rows where we tried to fill in the price:

```
/* -- dates --*/
declare @fromdate datetime, @thrudate datetime;
select  @fromdate = min(start_date), @thrudate = max(end_date) from @t;
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(datetime,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
    , [End_Date]=convert(datetime,dateadd(second,-1,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1)),@fromdate)))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                 cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
/* -- default price -- */
, cte as (
select 
    d.index_id
  , start_date = d.date
  , end_date   = d.end_date
  , t.gross_sales_price
  , t.net_sales_price
from (
  select dates.*
    , i.index_id
  from dates 
    cross join (select distinct index_id from @t) i
    ) d
  left join (select * from @t where store_id = 1) t
    on d.date >= t.start_date
   and d.date <= t.end_date
   and d.index_id = t.index_id
)
/* -- rows with a price */
select
    t.store_id
  , t.index_id
  , start_date
  , end_date
  , gross_sales_price
  , net_sales_price
from @t t
where t.Gross_Sales_Price is not null
union all 
/* -- rows with with a null price */
select 
    t.store_id
  , t.index_id
  , start_date = min(d.start_date)
  , end_date   = max(d.end_date)
  , gross_sales_price = d.gross_sales_price
  , net_sales_price = d.net_sales_price
from @t t
  left join cte d
    on t.index_id = d.index_id
   and d.start_date >= t.start_date 
   and d.end_date   <= t.end_date
where t.Gross_Sales_Price is null
group by 
    t.store_id, t.index_id, d.gross_sales_price, d.net_sales_price
order by store_id, index_id
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/QXDNF59094

returns:

```
+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| store_id | index_id |       start_date        |        end_date         | gross_sales_price | net_sales_price |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|        1 |       22 | 2014-08-30 00:00:00.000 | 2014-10-31 23:59:59.000 | 39.99             | 28              |
|        1 |       22 | 2014-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-09-30 23:59:59.000 | 20.99             | 15              |
|        3 |       22 | 2014-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 2014-12-30 23:59:59.000 | 20.99             | 15              |
|        3 |       22 | 2014-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2014-10-31 23:59:59.000 | 39.99             | 28              |
|        3 |       22 | 2014-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 2014-09-30 23:59:59.000 | 29.99             | 25              |
|        3 |       22 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2015-09-30 23:59:59.000 | 39.99             | 28              |
|        4 |       22 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-07-31 23:59:59.000 | 29.99             | 25              |
|        4 |       22 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2018-09-30 23:59:59.000 | 39.99             | 28              |
|        4 |       22 | 2016-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-12-30 23:59:59.000 | NULL              | NULL            |
|        4 |       22 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-09-30 23:59:59.000 | 20.99             | 15              |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

calendar and numbers tables reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops 2- Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)